# Blog Post webpart disappeared from post.aspx SharePoint 2013

Tags: blogs, sharepoint-2013

On my blog site on Post.aspx I edited the page, to modify the view so that we can remove the comments and likes from the posts. I saved my changes and the Post web part is no longer producing the post contents.

I have also completed the same process on the default.aspx Blog page and its just fine.

Please Please help.